# Java HttpHeaders - how to get user agent value?

Tags: java, http, junit, http-headers, user-agent

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
headers.set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0..."); //note - value hard coded
```

I am currently writing a `JUnit` test where I create a `RestTemplate` containing the above request headers.

I am hardcoding the `user-agent` header to be Mozilla currently, how can I add the actual user agent of from which the test is running here instead of hardcoding the value?

Comment: Just make [something](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#section-10.1.5) up if you need this header. Otherwise leave it undefined.

Comment: @AlexR why do you say this? Is not possible to get it programmatically?

Comment: Programatically from where? What do you expect the user-agent to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every HTTP client (or so called user agent) can define its own value for the `User-Agent` HTTP header. All major HTTP clients, like for example browsers or command-line tools like cURL and wget, do so.

Since you are in effect writing your own HTTP client via `RestTemplate`, it is up to you whether to define a value for that header or leave it undefined. If you choose to define the header, it should follow the rules given in the HTTP specification ([RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.3), or the current version [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110)).

To further answer your question: It seems like there was some [discussion](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17041) about setting a default value for that header for Spring Boot applications but it seems like the default value approach has not been implemented.